# Android Studio Serialization

Tags: android, kotlin, serialization

I have a Question. I have an App and store every data in the Class "Model" and I wanted to save it with serialization. This is the Model:

```
import android.os.Parcel
import android.os.Parcelable
import java.io.Serializable


private lateinit var att : IntArray
private lateinit var ess :String
private lateinit var skills : MutableList<IntArray>
private lateinit var attSkill : MutableList<IntArray>


class Model : Serializable {
    init {
        att = IntArray(9) { 1 }
        ess = "6"

      }


    fun getAttributes() : IntArray{
        return att
    }
    fun setAttributes(position : Int, value : Int){
        att[position] = value
    }   
}
```

And I Save it with:

```
 val fos = context.openFileOutput(filename, Context.MODE_PRIVATE)
            val os = ObjectOutputStream(fos)
            this.saveStuff()   //[Just write Attributes to model here]
            var newModel = controller.getModel()
            os.writeObject(newModel)
```

and Load it with:

```
  val fis = context.openFileInput(filename)
                val input = ObjectInputStream(fis)
                val model = input.readObject() as Model
                this.loadStuff(model)
                input.close()
```

Now I get this: Lets say I save values 1 2 3 4 with filename "test1" and after that I save values 4 3 2 1 in "test2". After that I load "test1" and get 4 3 2 1. In the matter of fact I just get the values my app has right in that moment of loading the data. Checked it in load function with Log.d().
After restarting the App if I load "test1" or "test2" I will get default values.

Am I missing something? Or is it just an example why people actually use Json for such things.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

att, ess etc. are no members of `Model`, snd therefore are not serialized to disk. Pull them into the class definition to fix that:

```
class Model : Serializable {

    private lateinit var att : IntArray
    private lateinit var ess :String
    private lateinit var skills : MutableList<IntArray>
    private lateinit var attSkill : MutableList<IntArray>

    init {
        att = IntArray(9) { 1 }
        ess = "6"

      }


    fun getAttributes() : IntArray{
        return att
    }
    fun setAttributes(position : Int, value : Int){
        att[position] = value
    }   
}
```

You will need to provide (de-)serialization logic for these attributes. Kotlin‘s @Parcelize annotation might be of interest here.

Comment: Epic Facepalm ... Thanks